# Cannot find governing FrameworkElement to DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame

Tags: wpf, binding, state, frameworkelement

I try to bind the value of `DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame`  to `HasError` of textbox:

```
<DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1,Path=Validation.HasError}"/>
```

It does not work.

I checked the output and saw the following error:

> Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for
>   target element. BindingExpression:Path=Validation.HasError;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame'
>   (HashCode=xxxxx); target property is 'Value' (type 'Boolean')

**Does anyone have any idea why this error occurs?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happens because key frames are abstract object that are not in any tree.

Also you cannot bind animations anyway if i remember correctly.